# read dat file in python shows UnicodeDecodeError (File <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>)

Tags: python, error-handling, io, word-wrap

I try to open a dat file but facing UnicodeDecode Error.

see the below code which i tried.

```html
with open(dat_file, 'r') as f:  (or)  with open(dat_file, 'r', errors = 'ignore') as f
    print('type of f :', type(f)) # for ref
    print('f : ', f) # for ref
    
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    
    for lines in data:
        print(lines)
    
Error

type of f : <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
f  : <_io.TextIOWrapper name='...\\dat_file\\test.dat' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-64afc3b0473f>", line 5, in <module>
    data = f.read()

  File "...anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 22332: character maps to <undefined>
```

When i open the `data in Variable explorer` it looks like ..

[image]

Requirement

**Alternate soln :**

if I try to convert `the dat file to .mat` file `using matlab.`

if i open the mat file using `scipy.io` as `f = sio.loadmat(file.mat).`

if i open the variable explorer it open as a dict & I can able to continue with my work through that dictionary. `f =` 
[image]

**Requirement :**

But i want to open the dat file in python directly, I am facing the error while reading in python.

Any leads would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the mode to "rb", the b means that python will read from the object byte-by-byte instead of char-by-char.
Since a (unicode-)char can consist of multiple bytes it can happen that some byte combination is read that does not correspond to a Unicode char, resulting in the error.

For more info, type help(open) in interactive python console.
help() is a great resource in general:)

Comment: i tried using 'rb', but i cannot able to achive what i needed. It returns '<class bytes>' when i use 'f.read()'. But hwo can i read information ??? @python00b